# Get clicked option in multiple oi.select angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

```
    <oi-select class="oi-select" 
        oi-options="student.name for student in students track by student._id" 
        multiple placeholder="" ng-model="class.students" ng-change="clickedName()">
    </oi-select>
```

This is multiple select options. I want to know the clicked option of the oi.select; both selected and deselected. How to write this in angular way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the clicked option by accessing the ng-model,

```
<oi-select class="oi-select" 
        oi-options="student.name for student in students track by student._id" 
        multiple placeholder="" ng-model="student" ng-change="clickedName()">
 </oi-select>
```

**`Controller:`**

```
console.log($scope.student);
```

Or you can pass the selected one via ng-change,

```
 <oi-select class="oi-select" 
            oi-options="student.name for student in students track by student._id" 
            multiple placeholder="" ng-model="student" ng-change="clickedName(student)">
 </oi-select>
```

**`Controller`**

```
$scope.clickedName = function(selected){
 console.log(selected.name);
}
```

Comment: I can't. It shows all students in $scope.class, not the one clicked!

Comment: @Atom_Awesome problem is you are using the same variable somewhere else. can you change the ng-model to just student and check? check the updated answer

Comment: I'm sorry. It doesn't work. Maybe I compare the two variables and get the difference. It might work?

Comment: @Atom_Awesome compare which variable? this is the angular way. do you have team viewer?

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'm not sure what I did wrong. You should check it sometime to be sure.